# How does event Loop in Javascript Work? How does process.nextTick and setImmediate Work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval, event-loop

1. whenever any 'setTimeout' and 'setInterval' completes, does event-loop transfer it's a callback to poll phase or execute that callback while it is in that phase?
2. does 'process.nextTick()' callbacks are called after every event loop phase? if not, when do the callbacks happen?
3. after the poll phase, which callbacks are called the first? 'process.nextTick()' or 'setImmediate()' (i think nextTick)

any good references for understanding event-loop are welcomed
thank you in advance

Comment: A very good and simple explanation as a reference, [What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=186s)

Answer (score 0):

1. No. Until poll phase is complete(!).
2. Any time you call process.nextTick() in a given phase, all callbacks passed to process.nextTick() will be resolved before the event loop continues. (Taken from doc)
3. After poll phase `setImmediate` callbacks are executed in check phase.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/